# "Restangular" Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, angular-module, angular-providers

I try to make authorization in my app with angular. 
I created app.service and injected "Restangular". And i have this error

```
Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error Failed to instantiate module cadastral due to:
Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error Failed to instantiate module Restangular due to:
Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable Module 'Restangular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I included all files in my html page

```
script src="/app/app/core/js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"
scrip src="/app/app/core/js/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"
script src="/app/app/core/js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"
script src="/app/app/core/js/restangular.js" type="text/javascript"
```

This is my app code

```
var app = angular.module('cadastral', ["ngRoute","ngResource",'ngCookies',"Restangular"]);
app.controller('authCtrl', function($scope,$http,$routeParams,AuthService,$cookies){
  /**/
});
```

Ant this is AuthService:

```
app.service('AuthService', function($cookies, $http, Restangular) {
/**/
  });
```

Can somebody help me? 
what's problem?

Comment: you removed the restangular module and you are confused why Angular can't find it anymore?

Comment: full error trace might also help

Comment: i added full error trace

Answer (score 0):

when you inject a third party module into your project module you should send module name as parameter...

In your case you are injecting **Restangular** which is not the module name for restangular change it to **restangular** and you should be fine...

Restangular is the name of its service not module...